# How do I use placeholder in Google Forms?

Tags: html, forms, browser, placeholder, google-forms

I have created a contact page using **Google Forms**. And I want to add a placeholder in this forms.

---

Before asking, I searched a lot on Google but I get no success. The only way I am able to do is by accessing Developer Tools in *Chrome Browser* by assigning `placeholder="some_name"` but that is of no use as it is for temporary basis.

[image: Using Developer tools for Placeholder]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't add a placeholder to a field in a Google Form.**

There is no way to dynamically change the HTML, CSS and JavaScript in a Google Form.  The Google Form is served directly from Google's servers.  There is no way to add and save HTML, CSS and JavaScript to the Form file.  If you try to open a Form file from Drive, there is only one option to open it with Google Forms.  You can't open a Google Form with a code editor, and you can't download it.  There is no way to run JavaScript code when the Form is first loaded.

Comment: How do I ask Google to add this feature as there are no any methods to add a placeholder in a Google Form?

Comment: To submit a feature request, open a Google Form, choose the "Help" menu, and then select "Report a Problem" from the list.

Comment: As per your instruction I have successfully submitted **a feature request** to **Google**. Hope to see them add it soon.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You can't add placeholders directly, but you may find this workaround useful. Go to:
(Old forms) "Responses->Get pre-filled URL"
(New froms) "More->Get pre-filled link"
Fill in the fields with values you need and click "Submit". You will get the link to the prefilled form with entered values in the fields 
[image]